# Deformation retraction and retraction of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I want construct a deformation retraction of $\mathbb{R}$ onto $[0,1]$. I really need some hints.

Comment: You could start by stating the definitions of retraction and deformation retraction and why you think these two statements should be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(There were two scenarios in the version of this question when I started this answer.  The first one seems to have been edited away in the interim.)

For the first one:  a retract is a continuous map that here fixes each point of $(0,1)$.  Where in $(0,1)$ does continuity force $0$ to be sent?

For the second one: Now that the endpoints, $0$ and $1$ can be fixed, it is enough to find a continuous parametric map that collapses the ray $(-\infty,0)$ to $0$ as the parameter runs from $0$ to $1$ and that similarly collapses the ray $(1,\infty)$ to $1$.  I observe that $x \mapsto (1-t)x$ is the identity at $t = 0$ and is identically $0$ at $t = 1$...  (I leave the other ray to you.)

Comment: I kind of figured out why $\mathbb{R}$ can't retract onto $(0,1)$ so I edited that part away.